# Using AVAudioPlayer, my sounds (sporadically!) play weird

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I've done a simple audio playback GUI implemented using AVAudioPlayer.

When playing my sound, I use a UISlider to provide playback feedback...

Here's where it gets weird.

I have a problem that happens very (very) sporadically - and mostly it doesn't happen, making it really hard to debug.

The problem is that sometime, once the sound ends, and I play it again, it's as if it starts looping (as if I set numberOfLoops to -1), without ever calling audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying.

Now, no where is my code do I "touch" numberOfLoops - it defaults to 0, and I leave it that way.

To make the problem weirder, then once this problem happens, I don't "hear" the audio - though it does appear to play (i have a timer function that provides the visual feedback, and it checks the sound is playing...)

Any ideas? Directions?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue once and I got around the issue by increasing the updating timer interval to .25 seconds,which was earlier .1 seconds. Also I tried to avoid files with very small duration. Hope this helps you to some extend. Please try it and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Before testing a fix, I must ask - did you find a way to get the problem to appear always? I'm asking, since I had/have a hard time reproducing the problem...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on some files whose duration was very less. I tested this fix on those files and was not able to reproduce that.

Comment: Before the fix I was able to reproduce the issue once every 5 or 6 attempts.

Comment: Sorry, not able to reproduce it - hence not able to test the proposed fix, hence slow in accepting the answer. I hope to get there later this week...